# На 10264 жителей или на 10264 жителя?

Tags: склонение, числительные, количественно-именное-сочетание

Как правильно: на 10264 жителей был наложен запрет или на 10264 жителя был наложен запрет?

Comment: @Верьясова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

на 10264 (на 10 тысяч двести шестьдесят четыре) жителя был наложен запрет.

Составные количественные числительные, оканчивающиеся на два, три, четыре, при склонении сохраняют в винительном падеже форму именительного даже в тех случаях, когда с ними сочетаются названия одушевлённых предметов: избрать тридцать три представителя, принять двадцать четыре посетителя, выдвинуть сто сорок два кандидата.

Только вот запрет накладывается не на жителей, а на что-то (ловлю рыбы, проезд, проживание). Запретить жителей - это как-то нереально, можно запретить им что-то делать.

Comment: спасибо, я тоже так думала

Comment: Предложение звучит так: Из-за долгов на 10264 жителей был наложен запрет на выезд за рубеж. Я думаю, что надо исправить жителей на жителя. Это точно Вин. падеж.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант:

*10264 жителям было запрещено заниматься тем-то и тем-то...*

> Предложение звучит так: Из-за долгов
> на 10264 жителей был наложен запрет на
> выезд за рубеж. Я думаю, что надо
> исправить жителей на жителя. Это точно
> Вин. падеж.

*Из-за долгов 10264 (десяти тысячам двумстам шестидесяти четырём) жителям был запрещен выезд за рубеж.*